# Unusual problem with Swoop on Mac OS 9.0.4 under SheepSaver

Tags: classic-mac-os

I have setup SheepSaver with Mac OS 9.0.4 and it boots okay. I've installed software and games. One of those games is Swoop http://www.ambrosiasw.com/games/swoop/

I can launch Swoop and play the game ok. But after I'm dead and try to play it again, the game starts but then freezes. The music and sound effects keep playing, but pressing the keyboard keys or moving the mouse has no effect. The only response I can get is by forcing SheepSaver to quit. When I launch SheepSaver again, I can play the game again, but only once. During that first game I can play for ages, but when I'm dead it freezes again upon trying to play it again. Very strange.

I used to play this game all the time in the Classic environment in OS X and never had any problems.

I've tried setting up SheepSaver on another Mac and have the same problem in that installation as well.

I've also tried changing the SheepSaver preferences - but all my changes have made things worse - the game either doesn't start or starts and freezes immediately.

My usual settings when the games works fine for one game are as described here http://www.emaculation.com/doku.php/sheepshaver_mac_os_x_setup

Does anyone have any ideas on what I can try next?

Comment: I used to love that game! :) Since you've already tinkered with the preferences, I have no initial suggestions to offer - but I will install it myself to see if the problem is replicated at my end! Will let you know how I go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry it's taken me a while to respond, but as promised in the comments I've tried to replicate this problem at my end.

The good news is that I could in fact replicate the problem. The problem occurs on five separate SheepSaver installations on three different Macs (running Tiger, Snow Leopard and El Capitan). I've tried various preference settings, along with experimenting with Mac OS 8.6 and Mac OS 9.0.4 installations. I've also tried booting SheepSaver with extensions off, and tried playing Swoop without sound.

Long story short, I couldn't play more than two consecutive games before SheepSaver froze.

As a final check, I tested Swoop on a standalone 2002 Quicksilver PowerMac G4 running Mac OS 9.2.2. Swoop plays flawlessly! :)

So, in a nutshell, I know this isn't the answer you were looking for, but I don't think you're going to get Swoop to work properly in SheepSaver. You could try some other emulation software, such as [Basilisk](http://www.emaculation.com/doku.php/basilisk_ii), or purchase an older Mac capable of booting directly into Mac OS 9 (or running the Classic environment under Mac OS X). If you happen to want to try the Classic environment, post a comment and I'll happily test this for you (I have a couple of Macs that can run Classic OS under OS X).

Either way, good luck!

Comment: Thank you Sir. I + 1 your answer but will wait to see if someone else offers a different answer before accepting yours. I hope you understand.

Comment: Absolutely! I really hope you get it working. :) And if you do, please share what you did.