# (SheepSaver error) Sorry, the desktop folder on the startup disk could not be created. Try unlocking the disk

Tags: classic-mac-os

I've been having problems with a SheepSaver installation (see my other question [Unusual problem with Swoop on Mac OS 9.0.4 under SheepSaver](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272345/unusual-problem-with-swoop-on-mac-os-9-0-4-under-sheepsaver)) so decided to start from scratch and create a second SheepSaver installation. But instead this time I followed the instructions from here http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/sheepshaverwrapper.html

All was going well, but when I get to step 3b I get this error

[image]
If I click OK, SHeepSaver just starts again and gives the same error.

The startup disk is a disk image created in Disk Utility and it has to be locked to work with sheepsaver, so its not like i can unlock it. Plus it's an image of the Mac OS 8.5.1 install CD.

I searched the various mac OS 9 / Sheepsaver forums, but this error message doesn't seem to be discussed anywhere.

What gives?

How do I fix it?

Any ideas welcome. :)

Comment: Are you sure it's Step 3a? Your question states _The startup disk is a disk image created in Disk Utility_, but I had a look at the link and you should be using Step 3b (not Step 3a).

Comment: Thank you sir! I have corrected my question. But the issue persists as I mistakenly had 3a in the question but was actually doing 3b.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a look at the [SheepSaver Wrapper](http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/sheepshaverwrapper.html) page you're using and think they've essentially been too clever by half. I followed it a few times and ran into various problems I then had to resolve myself.

If I was you, I would stick to the setup at [emaculation](http://www.emaculation.com/doku.php/sheepshaver_mac_os_x_setup) instead.

However, if you're going through all this effort to try and play Swoop (as per your other [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272345/unusual-problem-with-swoop-on-mac-os-9-0-4-under-sheepsaver)) I suggest it's just not worth the effort. Just my two cents worth.